# Java: How to insert elements from one array to another in specific sequence(homework)

Tags: java, arrays

I have a problem with Arrays.
UPDATE:
I need to insert elements from Array A to Array B, staring with uneven **indexes** and even ones afterwards. for example: A[0] should become B[10], A[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDjll.jpg)=B[0],A[2]=B[11] etc.
 I have updated the code (Thank you all for comments, tips and suggestions!).

```
        for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        if (i%2==1)
        B[C-1]=A[i];
        C++;
    }

    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
            if (i%2==0)
            B[C]=A[i];
            C++;
        }
```

Now it does fill Array B, but only every other element. See picture: [Right now output is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDjll.jpg)

How do get the B array to fill in right?

Sorry, if this all sounds stupid, I just started to learn programming.

Comment: does it fill array `B` at all?

Comment: Many logic errors, for one you are comparing if the index of A is even instead of the values from A.

Comment: If you have tested your input code and it works then it is not a necessary part of the question, so chop it out. The less code we have to look at, the more chance there is of someone a) bothering to look, b) finding the problems. Also, a tip for young players: Use `{ }` on your ifs, may make it clearer what you intended.

Comment: Not a terrible question, but please be clear about what you mean by "it does not work". What exactly does it do as compared with your expectations?

Comment: In the 2 for loops just after the do/while loop, you are assigning C=0 inside the for loop, and assigning the value to B[C] which will always assign the value to 0th index on array B. So, using C is useless inside both the for loops.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most elegant or efficient solution, but I think it's simple enough to understand and follow.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    double[] a = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    double[] b = new double[a.length];
    double[] tempArray = new double[a.length];

    int tempCounter = 0;
    int indexCounter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
        if (a[i] % 2 == 0){ // even
           tempArray[tempCounter] = a[i];
           tempCounter++;
        }else{
            b[indexCounter] = a[i];
            indexCounter++;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<tempCounter; i++){
        b[indexCounter] = tempArray[i]; 
        indexCounter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, after all suggestions, I was able to get it right!

```
        for (i=1; i<20; i++){
        if (i%2==1){
        B[C]=A[i];  
        C++;
        }
    }
        for (i=0; i<19; i++){
            if (i%2==0){
            B[C]=A[i];
            C++;
            }

        }
```